# Limit $\lim \limits_{h\to 0} \frac{\sqrt{3x+h}-\sqrt{3x}}{h}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm trying to solve a problem with two variables, but the limit only addresses one. Wolfram Alpha simplifies it for h. Should I leave it simplified, or does x need to be a real number?

$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\sqrt{3x+h}-\sqrt{3x}}{h}$$

[Wolfram Alpha's solution](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim%28sqrt%283x%2Bh%29-sqrt%283x%29%29%2Fh%2C+h%3D0).

Comment: You don't need to use Wolfram Alpha here. Multiply by $$\frac{\sqrt{3x+h}+\sqrt{3x}}{\sqrt{3x+h}+\sqrt{3x}}$$

Comment: What limit exactly are you trying to compute?You didn't mention any variable for the limit.

Comment: @oldrinb that's not what I mean. I meant whether or not I could simplify h.

Comment: @GitGud he did, ugly notation though...

Comment: @MiaCcio what does it mean to 'simplify $h$'?

Comment: Look at @graphths answer

Comment: @AlexR Right. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the notation

Comment: @MiaCcio no problem. Again what do you mean by "simplify $h$"?

Comment: @AlexR Sorry, I meant simplify for h. It means that x remains constant in the solution.

Comment: @MiaCcio actually, $h$ is no variable in the expression; it is "internal" to the limit.

Comment: @AlexR sorry I'm kind of new to this, school started two weeks ago.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the limit is as $h$ approaches 0, then the $x$ is not changing, only $h$ is.  So, $x$ is treated as if it were a constant in the calculation.

Answer (score 1):

Can you put the limit in the form $ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} $?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sqrt{3x+h}-\sqrt{3x}}{h}
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sqrt{3x+h}-\sqrt{3x}}{h}\frac{\sqrt{3x+h}+\sqrt{3x}}{\sqrt{3x+h}+\sqrt{3x}}\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(3x+h)-(3x)}{h(\sqrt{3x+h}+\sqrt{3x})}
\end{align}
$$